# tail_quantile "has initializer but incomplete type"

Tags: c++, boost

I wrote below simple program following boost 1.55 document

```
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/tail_quantile.hpp>

using namespace boost::accumulators;


void testTailQuantile()
{
    // tolerance in %
    double epsilon = 1;

    std::size_t n = 100000; // number of MC steps
    std::size_t c =  10000; // cache size
    typedef accumulator_set<double, stats<tag::tail_quantile<boost::accumulators::left> > > accumulator_t_left;
    accumulator_t_left acc1(boost::accumulators::tail<boost::accumulators::left>::left_tail_cache_size = c);
}
```

But I got below errors:

> In file included from ../src/LearnBoost.cpp:16:0:
>   ../src/testBoostAccumulator.h: In function ‘void testTailQuantile()’:
>   ../src/testBoostAccumulator.h:23:47: error: variable
>   ‘accumulator_t_left acc1’ has initializer but incomplete type
>   accumulator_t_left
>   acc1(boost::accumulators::tail::left_tail_cache_size
>   = c);
>                                                  ^ ../src/testBoostAccumulator.h:23:77: error: expected
>   primary-expression before ‘>’ token   accumulator_t_left
>   acc1(boost::accumulators::tail::left_tail_cache_size
>   = c);

So frustrated at Boost. Excellent framework, but makes life very difficult...

Comment: Try `typedef typename accumulator_set<...> accumulator_t_left;`. Notice the addition of the `typename`.

Comment: I think you are missing some header, adding `#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>` changes the error. Edit: The next error is solved by using simply "left_tail_cache_size" when you construct `acc1`.

Comment: `#include <boost/accumulators/framework/accumulator_set.hpp>` seems to be enough if you want to minimize your includes (although a similar problem may surface if you add something in the future).